# React doesn't update child state that depends on parent props

Tags: reactjs

I encountered such a problem that when we have a child component whose state depends on the props of the parent, this does not work quite correctly, I would like to know if it is possible to solve this problem using **useLayaoutEffect** or what is the best way?

Example

**Parent**

```
const Parent = () => {
    const  [filled, setFilled] = useState(false)
  useEffect(()=>{
   ..some logic
   setFilled(true)
  },[])
  return <Input isFilled={isFilled}/>
}
```

**Child**

```
const Input = (props) => {
  const  [filled, setFilled] = useState(props.isFilled || false)
  
  // when isFilled changes child components doens't notified about this changes,
  // so can we solve this with useLayoutEffect?

  useLayoutEffect(()=>{
   setFilled(props.isFilled || false)
 },[props.isFilled])
}
```

This example may be very simple and silly, but I think the essence of the problem should be clear.

Comment: `props` is not defined in your parent. Where is that coming from?

Comment: the problem is not from where props comming, but  children do not rerender if the props of the parent change, and if it's ok solve this problem with useLayaoutEffect

Comment: From your code, it looks like you don't have isFilled variable that you are passing down to the child. Looks like you should pass "filled" variable to the child prop

Comment: There has to be a dupetarget or 20 for this. Converting props to state [is usually an antipattern](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html), but the documentation [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-do-i-implement-getderivedstatefromprops) (which links to that previous article) shows how to do it.

Comment: My only suggestion is to make 100% percent sure that prop indeed does change (through browser inspector), and not to try to find complicated solution for a simple mistake